# How do I generate a Cyclonedx bom for a Java project built with Ant?

Tags: java, ant, owasp

I'm already generating boms and using them with Dependency Track for some projects built with Gradle. There's a CycloneDx Gradle plugin that works well for that. However I'm also working with many older Java projects that are built with Ant. I've not been able to find an Ant tool to generate the boms anywhere. Is there one out there? If not, what's the best way to generate the bom files?

If it can be done from a Windows command prompt, I can probably work with that as I'll add batch scripts to my Jenkins builds.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found an ANT integration. Also the CLI doesn't support creating of BOMs just yet, but there exists a Java Core of CycloneDX that should be able to generate the BOMs:
https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-core-java